# Return value if passes predicate, else default

Tags: rust, option-type, predicate

How can I replace a value if it fails a predicate?

To illustrate:

```
assert_eq!((3-5).but_if(|v| v < 0).then(0), 0)
```

I thought there would be something on `Option` or `Result` to allow this, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought there would be something on `Option` or `Result`

But neither of these types appear here. Subtracting two numbers yields another number.

It appears you just want a traditional if-else statement:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 3 - 5;
    assert_eq!(if a < 0 { 0 } else { a }, 0);
}
```

Since you have two values that can be compared, you may also be interested in `max`:

```
use std::cmp::max;

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(max(0, 3 - 5), 0);
}
```

---

You *can* make your proposed syntax work, but I'm not sure it's worth it. Presented without further comment...

```
fn main() {
    assert_eq!((3 - 5).but_if(|&v| v < 0).then(0), 0)
}

trait ButIf: Sized {
    fn but_if<F>(self, f: F) -> ButIfTail<Self>
        where F: FnOnce(&Self) -> bool;
}

// or `impl<T> ButIf for T {` for maximum flexibility
impl ButIf for i32 {
    fn but_if<F>(self, f: F) -> ButIfTail<Self>
        where F: FnOnce(&Self) -> bool,
    {
        ButIfTail(f(&self), self)
    }
}

struct ButIfTail<T>(bool, T);

impl<T> ButIfTail<T> {
    fn then(self, alt: T) -> T {
        if self.0 {
            alt
        } else {
            self.1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh god. Too much abstract error handling. I forgot how to use if-else statements. -_-

Comment: Thank you for taking my brain fart and running with it. Excellent answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** This got a bit nicer since [Rust 1.27](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1270-2018-06-21), when [`Option::filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.filter) was added:

```
assert_eq!(Some(3 - 5).filter(|&v| v >= 0).unwrap_or(0), 0);
```

---

Prior to Rust 1.27, you would have needed an iterator in order to write a single, chained expression without lots of additional custom machinery:

```
assert_eq!(Some(3 - 5).into_iter().filter(|&v| v >= 0).next().unwrap_or(0), 0);
```